# Creating new variable from several variables with same list of countries

Tags: variables, split, stata, intersection

In Stata I have split a variable where up to 20 countries were separated by a comma and now I have twenty different variables (`country1` to `country20`), but the same country is listed in more than one variable `country1` to `country20`.

For instance, Uganda may be in `country1`, `country2` and in `country5`. Now, I want to create one variable for each country (1 if true, 0 false). So, basically Iwant one variable for each of the twenty countries. I tried this but did not work.

```
local N = _N
forvalues i = 1/`N' {
    local s1 = Countryies1 [`i']
    local s2 = Countryies2   [`i']   
    local s3 = Countryies3 [`i']
    local s4 = Countryies4   [`i'] 
    local s5 = Countryies5 [`i']
    local s6 = Countryies6   [`i'] 
    local s7 = Countryies7 [`i']
    local s8 = Countryies8   [`i'] 
    local s9 = Countryies9 [`i']
    local s10 = Countryies10   [`i'] 
    local s11 = Countryies11 [`i']
    local s12 = Countryies12   [`i']   
    local s13 = Countryies13 [`i']
    local s14 = Countryies14   [`i'] 
    local s15 = Countryies15 [`i']
    local s16 = Countryies16   [`i'] 
    local s17 = Countryies17 [`i']
    local s18 = Countryies18   [`i'] 
    local s19 = Countryies19 [`i']
    local s20 = Countryies20   [`i'] 
    
    local intersection: list s1 & s2 & s3 & s4 & s5 & s6 & s7 & s8 & s9 & s10 & s11 & s12 & s13 & s14 & s15 & s16 & s17 & s18 & s19 & s20
    replace country ="`intersection'" in `i'
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't consistent about the spelling of your variables. More importantly, see the Stata tag for advice about giving data examples.

Comment: The first reason your code won't work is that string values can't be combined with logical operators. But I don't follow what you thought the code would do.

Comment: Thank you, Nick, I followed the second option and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work -- and does not in any sense rule out other solutions.

```
clear 
input str42 countries 
"Uganda"
"Uganda, Kenya"
"Uganda, Kenya, Tanzania"
"South Africa"
end 

gen id = _n 
save datasofar, replace 

keep id countries 
split countries, parse(,)
drop countries 
reshape long countries, i(id) j(which)
drop if missing(countries)
replace countries = trim(countries)
gen name = strtoname(countries)
levelsof name, local(names) 

gen new_id = _n 

foreach n of local names { 
    gen is_`n' = name == "`n'" 
    su new_id if is_`n', meanonly 
    label var is_`n' "`=countries[r(min)]'"
    local vars `vars' is_`n' 
}

collapse  (max) `vars', by(id)

merge 1:1 id using datasofar 

     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   is_Kenya   is_Sou~a   is_Tan~a   is_Uga~a                 countries        _merge |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1          0          0          0          1                    Uganda   Matched (3) |
  2. |  2          1          0          0          1             Uganda, Kenya   Matched (3) |
  3. |  3          1          0          1          1   Uganda, Kenya, Tanzania   Matched (3) |
  4. |  4          0          1          0          0              South Africa   Matched (3) |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Another kind of solution is to just to loop over the names, so

```
foreach c in Uganda Kenya Tanzania "South Africa" { 
     local C = strtoname("`c'") 
     gen is_`C' = strpos(countries, "`c'") > 0 
}
```

but watch out -- variations in spelling will bite you. They will bite with the earlier code too.